# Saving State of a ToggleButton in a RecyclerView in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView that gets data from a url that outputs json and loads a image using picasso and some other datas. Each item in the view has a image, name, date and a ToggleButton.

I implemented a setOnCheckedChangeListener for the toggle button to add the images that are toggled to a database.

What i would like to do is, when the user closes the app and opens it again I want the items that were toggled before and saved in the database to have their toggle button set to true.

What happens is even if there is only one value in the database, multiple toggle buttons get activated when the app is restarted.

How to avoid this and is there better way to implement this ?

Note: Only part of the code is added here.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImagesViewHolder imagesViewHolder, final int position) {
    imagesViewHolder.toggleFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                database.saveLiked(currentImage, mScreenWidth);                            
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
    });

    for (Image image : database.getAllData()) {
        if (image.getUrl().equals(currentImage.getUrl())) {
            imagesViewHolder.toggleFavorite.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

saveLiked method

```
public void saveLiked(Image currentImage,int mScreenWidth) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_IMAGE_CATNAME, currentImage.getAuthor());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE_URL, currentImage.getUrl());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Comment: Show the __saveLiked__ method of Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not only toggle on, but toggle off too.
I.e. try changing this

```
for (Image image: database.getAllData()) {
    if (image.getUrl().equals(currentImage.getUrl())) {
        imagesViewHolder.toggleFavorite.setChecked(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

to this

```
// unchecked by default, unless proven checked below
imagesViewHolder.toggleFavorite.setChecked(false);
for (Image image: database.getAllData()) {
    if (image.getUrl().equals(currentImage.getUrl())) {
        imagesViewHolder.toggleFavorite.setChecked(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView reuses views by just binding new data to them and your issue might manifest because RV resuses a view which had previously toggled button and you do not reset their 'toggled' state when re-binding to new data.